# Is there any connections between $\max_x \frac{xMx^\top}{xx^\top}$ and $\max_x \frac{xM^kx^\top}{xx^\top}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Fix a matrix $M$. 
Consider the following two quantities: 
$$
\lambda_1 = \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} \frac{xMx^\top}{xx^\top}
$$
$$
\lambda_k = \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} \frac{xM^kx^\top}{xx^\top}
$$

Any ideas if there are any connections (inequality?) between these two quantities?

Comment: I assume that your $x$ is a row-vector.  You should explicitly say so, since this is not the usual convention in linear algebra.

Comment: Yup. It's a row vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is real symmetric **and** its spectral radius happens to be its largest eigenvalue (note: the spectral radius is the largest *modulus* of the eigenvalues, not necessarily the largest eigenvalue), then $\lambda_k=\lambda_1^k$, but in general, the two quantities are not related to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any pointers somewhere that I can learn about the details of its proof?

Comment: @Daniel I haven't any relevant literature at hand, but the point is that the eigenvalues of $M^k$ are the $k$-powers of the eigenvalues of $M$, and $\lambda_\max(M)=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{xMx^T}{xx^T}$ for any real symmetric matrix $M$ (this is known as Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, which is a special case of [Courant-Fischer minimax principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)).